Cramer Rao bound for correlated parameters
I'm struggling with the Cramer Rao bound for target localization considering angularly correlated rcs.
Considering multistatic sensing, e.g. target localization, (refer to H. Godrich, A. M. Haimovich and R. S. Blum, "Target Localization Accuracy Gain in MIMO Radar-Based Systems," IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory, vol. 56, no. 6, pp. 2783-2803, June 2010.) the localization process is operated by not only estimating the xy-coordinate of the target, denoted as $(x,y)$, but also include the estimation of the nuance parameter $\alpha_{mn}$, representing the amplitude of each reflection path (including the impact of target's rcs).
I wonder why is it a common technique to estimate the amplitude along with the target location.
In addition, although it is common to assume that the rcs observed from different angles are independent, I wonder how to derive CRB that considers the angularly correlation of the rcs observed from different angles. That is, the amplitute $\alpha$ is angularly correlated.
